# Liquibase warning about SYS.DBA_RECYCLEBIN in Oracle 12c

Tags: java, oracle, liquibase

My initial change set was:

```
<changeSet id="1.2.0-01" author="Arya">
    <createIndex tableName="org_message" indexName="ix_org_message_userid_peerid">
        <column name="user_id"/>
        <column name="peer_id"/>
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

It was executed successfully without any warning.

Then I've deleted the executed `1.2.0-01` record from `DATABASECHANGELOG` table (Note: the created index still exists) and added an `indexExists` precondition to the changeset:

```
<changeSet id="1.2.0-01" author="Arya">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <indexExists indexName="ix_org_message_userid_peerid"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <createIndex tableName="org_message" indexName="ix_org_message_userid_peerid">
        <column name="user_id"/>
        <column name="peer_id"/>
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

In the execution, i saw this log:

> JdbcDatabaseSnapshot$CachingDatabaseMetaData -| Liquibase needs to
> access the DBA_RECYCLEBIN table so we can automatically handle the
> case where constraints are deleted and restored. Since Oracle doesn't
> properly restore the original table names referenced in the
> constraint, we use the information from the DBA_RECYCLEBIN to
> automatically correct this issue.
>
> The user you used to connect to the database (ORG_PLATFORM) needs to
> have "SELECT ON SYS.DBA_RECYCLEBIN" permissions set before we can
> perform this operation. Please run the following SQL to set the
> appropriate permissions, and try running the command again.
>
> ```
>  GRANT SELECT ON SYS.DBA_RECYCLEBIN TO ORG_PLATFORM;
> ```

But the change-set was executed successfully: a `1.2.0-01` record with 'MARK_RAN' is added to `DATABASECHANGELOG` table.

Is this warning an important issue that should be fixed or is it just a default logging (like mentioned in [CORE-2940](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2940) issue)?  I'm using liquibae `3.8.9` and oracle `12c`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a warning you can ignore. You can disable the warning using the property:

```
liquibase.oracle.ignoreRecycleBin=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get this to work, checked out the latest `liquibase` and it seems it should be:

```
liquibase.ignoreRecycleBinWarning=true
```